# Model Null Exception --> @if(Model.Count() > 0 )

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model

Here is the error i am facing. My code seems fine where i have two data models. Both models are stored in the database as table. Now in the CSHTML (Razor view page) it throws exception on

@foreach(var obj in Model)

But it says Model is Null. Please help to resolve the issue.

Here is the code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Dz4c.jpg)

Comment: you have to post the action code at least since you are creating a model there.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
@if (Model.Count() > 0)
{

<table class="table-bordered table-striped" style= "width: 100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>
                Work Order Number
            </th>
            <th>
                Part Number
            </th>
            <th>
                Welding Points
            </th>
            <th>
                Target Work Center
            </th>
            <th>
                Operator
            </th>
            <th>
                Standard Cycle Time
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var obj in Model)
        {

            <td width="30%">@obj.WorkOrderNumber</td>
            <td width="30%">@obj.PartNumber</td>
            <td width="30%">@obj.WeldingPoints</td>
            <td width="30%">@obj.TargetWorkCenter</td>
            <td width="30%">@obj.Operator</td>
            <td width="30%">@obj.StandarCycleTime</td>

        }
    </tbody>      
 </table>

}
else
{
   <p><strong>No Data to Display!</strong></p>

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).